# IONIC 2 RefrenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: android, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've been pulling my hair over this for quite a while now.

I'm trying to use Facebook Auth for Firebase. I have also initialized my app in app.module.ts 
But when I run the below-mentioned code on my Android device, I get

> "RefrenceError: firebase is not defined"

```
  signInWithFacebook(){
    var _authInfo

Facebook.login(['email'])
  .then((_response) => {
    console.log(_response)

    _authInfo = _response

    return this._FBUserProfile();

  }).then((success) => {
    this.TEST = "IM IN";
    let creds = (firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider as any).credential(_authInfo.authResponse.accessToken)
    let providerConfig = {
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.OAuthToken,
      remember: 'default',
      scope: ['email'],
    };
    this.af.auth.login(creds, providerConfig)
      .then((success) => {
        console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));
        this. Error += (JSON.stringify(success));
        this.UID =  success.auth.uid;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        this. Error += (JSON.stringify(error))
      });

  })
  .catch((_error) => { this. Error +=(_error)  }) //Error caught here.


}



 _FBUserProfile() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture.width(100).height(100).as(picture_small),picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', [])
      .then((profileData) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(profileData));
        return resolve(profileData);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        return reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

And these are my imports.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthProviders, AngularFireAuth, FirebaseAuthState, AuthMethods, AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';
```

Also, note that I have run `npm install firebase angularfire2 --save` in the project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this:

`firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider`

but you are not importing firebase, even you import angularfire you need import firebase if you use it like you are using.

So try adding this:

`import * as firebase from 'firebase';`